A compiled list of different functionality kdb provide via ! operators along with negitive numbers ( e.g -11! `tplogs)
I am looking to find list of different functionality that kdb provides via different calls such as -11! ( replay logs ), -26! ( SSL details )... etc.. I want to see if there is a place where I can find consolidated details of all features provided by these calls ?

They are documented in the official Kx docs here: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/internal/
